# purpose of very long $_GET variables

Tags: php

for example: facebook uses very long variable for advertising links. Is there any special purpose for that?

example: `https://www.facebook.com/a.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FNkCrsK&__tn__=%2AI&xt=3.AQKkT8gw-9VNe6_eNeYfQfQZK2nDDVu33z9lBnGELdf-Mvl3ck0kYyK7qb93tfZvtcVJkNG4YOUsyKwSJbKhg68iMI2J4UKsjQ_DG1eKvCck3PjrQzcYDFYcn-tfF65ItAz9mwaslmt9c5L7xkmJJ9L_wjOPoALXiirlcz8imjv8aQ30XZ79OPGZTXqyn2dcHG_goLRnrO08PvvFERAyWSIRAL6K9Hj8sGfQByT3ZMrc-9EIC7DxjDuLoxAFH_B5Ee0uGssj3ECKNnwdhuJLo-JKj2USVoTdP9RxNhA8eSvHg2fD0GM_Vh2mFkseJyq31j3A9SGkGg6G6ro6B2hBtM_0RyEWo5LH8OFySYgd_JH59rTYJquYZnPMsEb94wk_-ABRoz5z0f0eRP7lH-Tfqs33nZWDVfnQC30LizMJdMLy6MBcOrRgpJjNf8V3Ked33fE54GFocw2V4L9oHlFh6g4PVIjofSDceN91tboaM7QJoeDlQw1Wk_dnuvvq0LXdDHOAXYGDfyHTWn586cyH-GkJYM1p8DZGzSVzuwQOBHkLD8uL7FNs6PoJPLc41lqdOUlUKNI5QLi1xCUsjM9xguFb2MW3vrqdJmr1Jxm2_0KOb3I6VM-of6SWOwySSJc-vVgoOGAfvcxmJACnSPD9v5S4kfozu6bhj3t1hzNvbUFuLBVxu-cJUNbDMZksOjOX5YdjYIRvlC8T2r5WNB09_Uf6YveP9BDxYwc3JA2XnzvGzBe3iMtZNlNqoAbCFXkZsj2eawUeMtQ98hCr-w40_qYw6XtgpVAQCX_dQDI3kNLhrCPX8PxxE17U564KO5HUGHy7_zVFVN15_CthSyTq38MqNRNam4Vpnt1g_BuVDU75rHEolwCqKVkwxUtS-pppjY5AcJlZ22ZXJxaNhOPzeqsnoFY8i0srtlYYnIhirv6_YfQZSDLWY5hLmiaWdLBqpKIUVNzcqC-QyH1fN1g2L6KsSS_P_ePt7Q8n0rGsm8hn1GeZrGBHBMINGzHL3O2VsaHKpO4_ljvtgTkvzoN2anoc4CT4J1xVkd9bBd_xOvhEx8SGYBo5GdEQJoAumazN3WWw5nq1DuMveuQ2kpSufE_ZQZJ1F5jWgwm1aeCMndwGhXZdb50AQzKZ87lzptUliVMajgpC38Oe53ao19Q6pwhDFYJFqQ2e3qpafLmr2rXp0mcnhPDcaVZhWhjDhbfH86QkpTF4i4NO29tULtJPkvJ5AFQ0Ecn2xpB7lvA1ok6MD45IXk_U6Hmyt5d35OY3T733P0AK53jwrhV3L0bwOsEAIOrNV0wsybZkYaH_FTw0ZncWnAOeNgatmXoVgnW5Tr_dy1HNhZ_ULRERXGPl071hVBYnOkXqtWLQ9RcDe3PHDwyiYWLgsINnddgbwMJEivpLVMcN-6foEhKxjimiDNEjp0K19QNd_Tc3rluKR4EeFK8HQFXonflhdaZk-Gj03nUPM2sRqzsqQjS01DPeTOlfs8OmHpXhjo7XdYhzLcttpSA21XuGCDHMR3hCzLJCyQOTtBLk6bE88QLBlJ8AlZtd5EpsAdgVSB9uc0SXof8mJFBTKsVTLkqmZK6yibkcaBNoe729qxxMDZm7jEs0QCcOtP0Xt3u71qp5kbDxEQ0YOVYOwXPrvKe1vt1KLXDPAfagBZCGPmOhR8qdkh2OMaJWkL3koLaaA6y0fpPQQpkpwhfaU1zk_LxUXK_JclHkR3hFcmfd9cnmL5PXty8wekjydeuaWzjFjitP60Yk7M3jErTe08qs0xYkjZCCWtBXJYRpPFiCoX_6z_B7DnAi8kPgIRi-KbffHcrjfFbdKrkSng&mac=AQJuF7HqXJnVzkpr&sig=122753`

Comment: Maybe. But only Facebook knows what it's for.

Comment: Those are in encrypted format..So it looks like big one...

Comment: ehrm... to be able to send more data then when using very short query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.php?` is indicating it's an advertisement on facebook.

If you take a look at the `u` query string, it's equal to `http://goo.gl/NkCrsK&__tn__=...` it's an encoded link with a few more query string values.

If you navigate to http://goo.gl you'll see it's a url shortenening service provided by google.  So the `u` probably stands for URL and the rest of the URL is encoded.

The specific URL it links to is http://goo.gl/NkCrsK, which redirects you to `http://46.20.14.130/~inanilma/uzmanlari/`

This is a doctors website.  The rest of the query string parameters probably correlate to the ad campaign the doctor signed up for on facebook so he can track his click throughs and the like.